# Why casting double to int might give different results?

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion

I am using fixed decimal point number (using uint16_t) to store percentage with 2 fractional digits. I have found that the way I am casting the double value to integer makes a difference in the resulting value.

```c
const char* testString = "99.85";
double percent = atof(testString);
double hundred = 100;
uint16_t reInt1 = (uint16_t)(hundred * percent);
double stagedDouble = hundred * percent;
uint16_t reInt2 = (uint16_t)stagedDouble;
```

Example output:

```
percent:      99.850000 
stagedDouble: 9985.000000
reInt1:       9984
reInt2:       9985
```

The error is visible in about 47% of all values between 0 and 10000 (of the fixed point representation). It does not appear at all when casting with `stagedDouble`. And I do not understand why the two integers are different. I am using GCC 6.3.0.

> Edit:
>   Improved code snippet to demonstrate `percent` variable and to unify the coefficient between the two statements. The change of `100` into a `double` seems as a quality change that might affect the output, but it does not change a thing in my program.

Comment: Casting to integer is truncating the fractional part. I guess you can take it from here.

Comment: are you compiling in 32-bit mode? Then it's due to the higher precision of x87 registers. There are a lot of duplicates: [C fundamentals: double variable not equal to double expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37626687/995714), [Apparently identical math expressions with different output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33795031/995714), [Difference in casting float to int, 32-bit C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54881541/995714), [Difference in floating point arithmetics between x86 and x64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710272/995714)

Comment: or maybe `percent` is a `float`? then it's a different issue

Comment: @ryyker This is not the case here. It is not about reinterpreting the bit-pattern.

Comment: How have you defined `percent` ?

Comment: Are you sure it is 47%? I measure 42.33%.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The conversion to integer explains why some results give values less than one might expect. It does not explain why the two methods, both of which convert to the same integer type, differ.

Comment: @phuclv, your comment with links to similar problems seems to explain my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apparently identical math expressions with different output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795031/apparently-identical-math-expressions-with-different-output)

Answer (score 2):

Is `percent` a float? If so, look at what types you're multiplying.

`reInt1` is `double * float` and `stagedDouble` is `int * float`. Mixing up floating point math can cause these types of rounding errors.

Changing the 100's to be both `double` or both `int` results in the same answer.

Comment: percent is not a float, it is another double. Changing 100 to be in both uniform in both statements `100` or `100.0` does not change anything for me.

Answer (score 2):

The reported behavior is consistent with `percent` being declared `float`, and the use of IEEE-754 basic 32-bit and 64-bit binary floating-point for `float` and `double`.

```
uint16_t reInt1 = (uint16_t)(100.0 * percent);
```

Since `100.0` is a `double` constant, this converts `percent` to `double`, performs a multiplication in `double`, and converts the result to `uint16_t`. The multiplication may have a very slight rounding error, up to ½ ULP of the double format, a relative error around 2<sup>−53</sup>.

```
double stagedDouble = 100 * percent;
uint16_t reInt2 = (uint16_t)stagedDouble;
```

Since `100` is an `int` constant, this converts `100` to `float`, performs a multiplication in `float`, and converts the result to `uint16_t`. The rounding error in the multiplication may be up to ½ ULP of the `float` format, a relative error around 2<sup>−24</sup>.

Since all of the values are near hundredths of an integer, a 50:50 ratio of errors up:down would make about half the results just under what is needed for the integer threshold.  In the multiplications, all those with values that are 0, 25, 50, or 100 one-hundredths would be exact (because 25/100 is ¼, which is exactly representable in binary floating-point), so 96/100 would have rounding errors. If the directions of the `float` and `double` rounding errors behave as independent, uniform random variables, about half would round in different directions, producing different results, giving about 48% mismatches, which is consistent with the 47% reported in the question.

(However, when I measure the actual results, I get 42% differences between the `float` and `double` methods. I suspect that has something to do with the trailing bits in the `float` multiplication before rounding—the distribution might not act like a uniform distribution of two possibilities. It may be the OP’s code prepares the `percent` values in some way other than dividing an integer value by 100.)

Comment: After the code in question has been changed to use double everywhere (instead of float), the answer becomes irrelevant. The real answer is in comments to the question.